# What is the syntax to return a function within a function in wordpress functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

What would be the appropriate solution to call a return function within another return function in wordpress?

Here is what I got:

```
// Related Posts Function, matches posts by tags - call using joints_related_posts(); )
function joints_related_posts() {
global $post;
$tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID );
if($tags) {
    foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
        $tag_arr .= $tag->slug . ',';
    }
    $args = array(
        'tag' => $tag_arr,
        'numberposts' => 1, /* You can change this to show more */
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'post_views_count','orderby' => 'DESC'
    );
    $related_posts = get_posts( $args );
    if($related_posts) {
    echo '<related-h4>SEE MORE:</related-h4>';
    echo '<related-post id="joints-related-posts">';
        foreach ( $related_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            <li class="related_post">
                <a class="entry-unrelated" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'byline' ); ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; }
        }
wp_reset_postdata();
echo '</ul>';
}


add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );

function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {

$related_posts_code = 'return joints_related_posts()';

if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( ($related_posts_code), 2, $content );
}

return $content;
}
```

The function `return joints_related_posts()` is what I'm trying to call within the function `return prefix_insert_after_paragraph(`, how can I do this?

Comment: makes no sense, return stops the function at that point.and you are saving the function you want to run as a string...are you sure you dont just want to put your function call inside the function args? `return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( (joints_related_posts() ), 2, $content );`

Comment: Hi, yes that is what I wanted, :) I have edited the question to show the joints_related_posts() code as when I add your code it messes with the whole post layout content.

Comment: for example 1. is what happens with the new code, and 2. is just using the function by itself http://s32.postimg.org/h4w8r0xhh/code.jpg

Comment: nevermind I had: display: inline-flex; in the css, fixed it